# equivalent of limit with to parameter in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mysql query as follow:

select * from table limit 3,100

But I do not really know how to convert it to mongo, for example if the 3 was not in the query it was easy to do that like as follow:

```
db.userdetails.find().limit(2)
```

but with limit 3,100 I do not really know how to do it, Is it possible to do this in mongo at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
db.userdetails.find().skip(3).limit(100)
```

This will skip the first 3 elements of the result set and take the 100 following elements

Comment: Be careful with this approach. Skipping is slow in MongoDB. As a rule of thumb, skipping more than 1,000 will start to hurt badly. Use range queries on monotonic sort keys if you need larger skips.